# Intercepting browser errors even if wrapped in try catch

Tags: javascript, runtime-error, overriding, try-catch

So as the title states I would like to be able to intercept all errors that occur on the page. So starting off with the simplest way:

1. Add an error event listener to window and store the errors as they occur

The problem with this approach is that if the code that is causing the error is wrapped in a try catch block, the error listener never gets triggered.

A partial solution to this issue is to override the Error constructor so that any time code such as `throw new Error()` is called we can intercept it using our override. This approach works very nicely for user generated errors, this doesn't work for errors that originate in the browser. For example:

```
    const a = ()=> {
        const b = {};
        console.log(b.c.d) // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'c' of undefined
    }

    try {
        a()
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
```

I would like to be able to detect that a TypeError has been thrown. Overriding the TypeError constructor does not work in this case.

Any ideas?

EDIT: The point is to be able to intercept errors that 3rd party scripts wrap with a try catch

Comment: i believe that's not possible without some built-in browser specific functionality. The whole purpose of catch{} is to handle the exception and not let it pass through. If you want to see all exceptions, why not simply remove all catch {} blocks and let them fall through to a single catch handler in the root of the app?

Comment: Well the point is to be able to intercept errors that 3rd party scripts wrap with a try catch.